# Error: Could not access built-in Node.js modules

Tags: javascript, next.js, cloudflare-pages

I deploy next js on cloudflare pages and get an error like this :
Error: Could not access built-in Node.js modules. Please make sure that your Cloudflare Pages project has the 'nodejs_compat' compatibility flag set.

I tried to search the forum and didn't find an answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just happened with my Next.js project. After successfuly building and deploying I saw this error on my project URL: `Error: Could not access built-in Node.js modules. Please make sure that your Cloudflare Pages project has the 'nodejs_compat' compatibility flag set.`

Added `nodejs_compat` flag and retried deployment and voila, it works now.

However, the documentation is a bit unclear about how to enter "nodejs_compat" flag from Cloudflare dashboard  -> Workers & Pages -> Your Pages project -> Settings -> Functions -> Compatibility Flags. It only gives example regarding putting it inside wrangler.toml as this format:

```
compatibility_flags = [ "nodejs_compat" ]
```

If you want to enter "nodejs_compat" flag from Cloudflare dashboard, you need to enter this flag with bare words: `nodejs_compat`. Nothing else, no quotation marks, no other words (no brackets or anything else) and it will work.

Comment: That's an excellent comment! I would expect that this flag is set be default if you've selected Next.js as a framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the documentation for compatibility flags at https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/configuration/compatibility-dates/#compatibility-flags

To enable Node.js APIs you'll have to add

> `compatibility_flags = [ "nodejs_compat" ]`

to your `wrangler.toml` file.

Alternatively you can set compatibility flags in your Cloudflare dashboard by following [these](https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/platform/functions/get-started/#runtime-features) steps:

> - Log into the [Cloudflare dashboard](https://dash.cloudflare.com/) and select your account.
> - Select **Workers & Pages** and select your Pages project.
> - Select **Settings** > **Functions** > **Compatibility Flags**.
> - Configure your Production and Preview compatibility flags as needed.

Comment: As of December 12, 2023, there is no 'Functions' option under 'Settings.' Only 'General' and 'Variables' options are available.

Comment: @Rem I guess Wrangler is the only solution at the moment